Null or Undefined for Prop in Component?
I need to set a default value for a prop...
 imageAlt: {
        type: String,
        default: null,
    },

But should the default be null or undefined?

Depends. Is it supposed to be empty or not populated. Does it even make a difference? Depending on what you want to have there given the image context, I recommend checking a few things. I forgot exactly how it renders in the DOM but there are a few things to consider.

Undefined means a variable has been declared but no value is assigned to it.  Null is explicit and means that a variable has been assigned no value.  Since you plan on generally having a value for that prop, you should use Null.
What is the difference between null and undefined in JavaScript?
